# React - How to get current state values in custom hooks with redux-toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've got a question. I have a custom hook like this:

```
import { isNullOrUndefined } from '../../../../../../utils/utils';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export const useGoodsSetupWizardController = () => {
    const productSetupWizard = useSelector((state) => state.productSetupWizard.value);

    function isNextButtonDisabled() {
        let returnValue = false;
        switch(productSetupWizard?.step) {
            case 2:
                if(isNullOrUndefined(productSetupWizard?.product?.productName) || productSetupWizard?.product?.productName.trim().length === 0) {
                    returnValue = true;
                }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    return {
        isNextButtonDisabled,
    };
}
```

As you can see I'm using `useSelector` to get the current value of `productSetupWizard`.
In my other components and hooks all is working fine using this way.
The slice is this one here:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  value: { 
    step: 1, 
    product: null 
  },
};

export const productSetupWizardSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'productSetupWizard',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setProductSetupWizard: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload
    },
    increaseStep: (state, action) => {
      state.value.step++;
    },
    decreaseStep: (state, action) => {
      state.value.step--;
    }
  },
});

export const { setProductSetupWizard, increaseStep, decreaseStep } = productSetupWizardSlice.actions;

export default productSetupWizardSlice.reducer;
```

I don't know if you need to see the store file here to answer my question. If so, please let me know. I will add them to my question then.
The question I have, it seems not be working in a custom hook like the code above.
It gives me always the initial value of `productSetupWizard` and not updates on it.

Is it because the custom hook is initialized once on the component body with the initial value of `productSetupWizard`?

So my question is, is there any special usage in custom hooks necessary to get the state values from React-redux (toolkit)?

So the value of productSetupWizard in method isNextButtonDisabled() is always the initial value:

```
 value: { 
        step: 1, 
        product: null 
      },
```

Here is the complete way of importing the different custom hooks I use in my project.
I have a hook called `ProductSetupWizard`. This is my UI. This ProductSetupWizard is importing the function `getController` from the custom hook called `useProductTypeSetupWizard`:

```
import { useProductTypeSetupWizard } from '../../../../factories/productSetup.factory';

function ProductSetupWizard(props) {
    const [productSetupController, setProductSetupController] = useState(null);
    ...
    const { getController } = useProductTypeSetupWizard();
    ...
    
    useEffect(() => {
            setProductSetupController(getController(productTypeId));
    },[productTypeId]);
   
    return (
        <>
        ...
        </>
    );
}
```

The `useProductTypeSetupWizard` hook is loading and returning the `useGoodsSetupWizardController` depending on the given `productTypeId`:

```
import { isNullOrUndefined } from "../utils/utils";
import { useGoodsSetupWizardController } from '../components/managementInterface/shop/tabs/productSetupWizard/setups/goodsSetupWizard.controller';

export const useProductTypeSetupWizard = () => {
    const {
        getComponentGoodsController,
        isNextButtonDisabledGoodsController,
        needsNextStepToBeSkippedGoodsController
    } = useGoodsSetupWizardController();

    function getController(productTypeId) {
        if(isNaN(parseInt(productTypeId))) {
            return null;
        }
        switch(parseInt(productTypeId)) {
            case 1:
                return {
                    getComponent: getComponentGoodsController,
                    isNextButtonDisabled: isNextButtonDisabledGoodsController,
                    needsNextStepToBeSkipped: needsNextStepToBeSkippedGoodsController
                };
            case 3:
                //apply like useGoodsSetupWizardController
        }
    }

    return { 
        getController
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you include an example where you use `useGoodsSetupWizardController`?

Comment: Yeah sure, please see my update.

Comment: And what about where `useProductTypeSetupWizard` is used? Or where this is ultimately used in a component? My guess is that you're using a stale version of `productSetupWizard` in `isNextButtonDisabled` by currying or memoizing somewhere.

Comment: The `ProductSetupWizard` component is the UI. It loads `getController` from `useProductTypeSetupWizard` in the function body. This custom hook returns then depending on the given `productTypeId` the functions of `useGoodsSetupWizardController`. I know, it is confusing... ;-)